# Spark Context Issue with Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-spark

I wrote a Spring boot application using Apache Spark. It works on my machine perfectly but when I tried to deploy it on a VM (Debian 9 with 4 GO of memory , 2 vCPU and 60 GB of storage) and run it  , it throws this exception : Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is already an RpcEndpoint called LocalSchedulerBackendEndpoint.

I added the option : set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true") and it didn't work also.

I don't use multiple contexts in my program, here's the code :

```
public Set<Customer> retrieveCustomers(String a) {
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spring boot app ")
                .setMaster("local[2]")
                .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true") ;

         JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

    final List<String> stopWords = getStopWords(ctx).collect();
    List<Tuple2<String, Tuple3<String,String,String>>> collect = getCompanies(ctx).collect();
    a = cleanText(a.substring(0,1000));
    String allTextLowerCase = a.toLowerCase();
    JavaRDD<Customer> words = ctx.parallelize(Arrays.asList(SPACE.split(a)))
            .filter(word -> isNotStopWord(word,stopWords))
            .filter(word -> ! word.trim().isEmpty())
            .map(word -> toDenomination(collect,word,allTextLowerCase))
            .filter(Objects::nonNull);
    Set<Customer> customers = new HashSet<>( words.collect());
    System.out.println("Total found Words :" + customers.size());
    ctx.cancelAllJobs();
    ctx.stop();
    System.clearProperty("spark.driver.port");

}
```

Do you have any solution for my problem ? why the application has initialized multiple Spark contexts on the server while in localhost , it does not.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to inject the context as another regular Spring Bean instead of the manual instantiation? It should work anyway but I guess that is the proper way of using Spring.

Where are you calling this method from? How many times?

It seems like multiple threads are accessing the method simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try this option. I'm calling the method once , from a REST service